# Which one is correct? (Present Perfect Continuous vs Present Perfect)

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect

1. My sister and her boyfriend have not been going out together for a long time.

Or

2. My sister and her boyfriend have not gone out together for a long time.

Comment: Both are correct.  I can't figure how to say more, without knowing:  is there a reason to think one of them might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct.  They mean different things.

1. *My sister and her boyfriend have not been going out together for a long time.*

They stopped dating each other a long time ago (to be going out = to be dating each other).

2. *My sister and her boyfriend have not gone out together for a long time.*

They are, quite possibly, still 'dating' but they have not actually been out together (on a date) for a long time. (to go out = (er...) to go out!)